# Прописные и строчные

Tags: прописная-строчная

Нужно ли здесь слова "профессионалов" писать оба раза с прописной буквы?

А самым главным фактором в формировании  нашего имиджа я считаю нашу команду профессионалов, профессионалов с большой буквы!

Answer (score 2):

В Нацкорпусе пишут с прописной буквы:

Это был Момент, Момент с большой буквы (Анатолий Рыбаков).

А как проговоришь с ним десяток минут ― видишь, что он полный Профан и Невежда ― (оба слова с большой буквы) (Ю. О. Домбровский).

Также: История не просто девушки, а Женщины с большой буквы.

Причем даже так — Любовь. Именно с большой буквы.

Где ваше собственное Я, Я с большой буквы.

Или его жуткий в своей правдивости блокадный цикл, или Петербург Достоевского ― это Искусство с большой буквы.

Тогда можно написать так:

А самым главным фактором в формировании нашего имиджа я считаю нашу команду Профессионалов, именно Профессионалов с большой буквы!

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что так логичнее. Если уж в тексте говорится, что пишется с большой, то нужно и писать с большой. Спасибо за поиск.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, здесь нет причин писать с прописной буквы.

Comment: Спасибо. Я думала, что просто надо как-то визуально подтвердить, что "профессионал" в данном контексте пишется с большой.

Comment: Если вам необходимо как-то выделить это слово, можете в тексте написать его в курсивом или как-то по-другому выделить.